# How to Access RDD Tables via Spark SQL as a SnowFlake datawarehouse JDBC Distributed Query Engine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I want to query my temp database table from snowflake db.

Similary [like How to Access RDD Tables via Spark SQL as a JDBC Distributed Query Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493026/how-to-access-rdd-tables-via-spark-sql-as-a-jdbc-distributed-query-engine)

Is there any way to do this from snowflake database running on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm - you want Snowflake to query the RDD that is created by Spark?

There is no way to connect from Snowflake to Spark and to query Spark RDDs from Snowflake
But you can connect from Spark to Snowflake, copy the RDD to Snowflake, and then query it either from Spark (e.g. using [`Utils.runQuery()`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements) or from Snowflake directly.

More info, with examples, in [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#moving-data-from-spark-to-snowflake)

P.S. Snowflake is a single word :)

Comment: Corrected my words. just want to confirm this kind of feature is present or not. Now I got it.